# MySql whole query returns Error 1690 while parts of it doesn't

Tags: mysql

I know that Error 1690 is nothing new in mysql but after searching for solution here i just gave up. So here I go, the error I get is:

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(v_from@10 - p_from@1)'
```

The problem is, I do not have any substraction in my query... honestly i even removed "-" from DATE_FORMAT!

My query is:

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
select count(distinct user_id) as 'event_count_dis',count(user_id) as 'event_count',DATE_FORMAT(event_time,'%Y%m') as 'data',
getEventCourse(event_desc) as 'Name'
from sys_events c where DATE_FORMAT(event_time,'%Y%m') like '201809'
and event_type in ('Clicked')
group by  getEventCourse(event_desc)
order by count(distinct user_id) desc Limit 20
```

Function getEventCourse(event_desc) works perfectly as it is very simple.

When i dissect this query and tested every part of it separately, everything worked fine... and I just gave up... Maybe some of you have any idea what's wrong? or at least can tell me what the heck is

```
'(v_from@10 - p_from@1)'
```

Function getEventCourse:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE courseName varchar(100);
IF(LOCATE('cid',description) > 0) THEN
    SET courseName =  (Select courses_name from sys_courses where courses_id = test_baza.extract_json_value(description,'cid'));
ELSEIF(LOCATE('course_id',description) > 0) THEN
    SET courseName =  (Select courses_name from sys_courses where courses_id = test_baza.extract_json_value(description,'course_id'));
ELSE
    SET courseName = null;
END IF;
RETURN courseName;
END
```

sys_events:

```
event_id | event_time | event_desc                            | event_type  | user_id
1537919  | 2018-10-12 | {"course_id":"386","element_id":"498"}|     Clicked | 1235
```

Edit:
Ok, it seems that problem appears in "group by" section.

Comment: `works perfectly`?  Can you include the code for `getEventCourse`?  I think this is where the problem is, and right now we can't see what that UDF is doing.

Comment: Also please add sys_events definition and if this is not a standalone query add the stored program (procedure,function,event,trigger) that it is part of.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is a standalone query that relies only on getEventCourse function which as you can see is quite simple.

Comment: event_desc is a varchar (because of old mysql version) formated as json. The only format possible to be returned is the one visible, since it depends on event_type, the only difference between event_desc in result sets are values of course_id and element_id keys.

Comment: Please add code for eskk_test_baza.extract_json_value

Comment: extract_json_value is standard function from common_schema framework for mysql. https://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/extract_json_value.html